# HABTM with AR enum scope

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, enums, associations

How can I have a model associated with a subset of records from the same model, defined by an AR enum scope?

I thought something like the following would work, but it doesn't. I'd be open to using `has_many :through` if it would simplify things, but it seems like overkill right now.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  enum role: [:doctor, :patient, :clinician]
  has_and_belongs_to_many :doctors, &:doctor?, class_name: "User"
end
```

Correcting to the suggested version gives a syntax error;

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  enum role: [:doctor, :patient, :clinician]
  has_and_belongs_to_many :doctors, &:doctor, class_name: "User"
end
```

error:

```
SyntaxError: ~/m2/app/models/user.rb:3: syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting keyword_end
  has_and_belongs_to_many :doctors, &:doctor, class_name: "User"
                                             ^
```

Using the `->{doctor}` syntax works, but I'd like to know why the `&` syntax is wrong.

Ok see below why the `&` syntax is wrong, and apparently the :doctor.to_proc trick doesn't work because to_proc binds the current object to the proc whereas it should be passed in to the proc, which means that `->{}` or `Proc.new{}` really is necessary in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the `scope` proc is evaluated in the class context (well, technically the relation context, which inherits class methods from your model). For example, from the [docs for `has_and_belongs_to_many`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-has_and_belongs_to_many-label-Scopes):

```
has_and_belongs_to_many :projects, -> { includes :milestones, :manager }
```

With this code, calling `SomeModel.projects` will be equivalent to calling `SomeModel.projects.includes(:milestones, :manager)`. Now, here's your code:

```
has_and_belongs_to_many :doctors, &:doctor?, class_name: "User"
```

With this code, calling `User.doctors` will be equivalent to calling `User.doctors.doctor?`, which doesn't work, because `doctor?` is an instance method on User, not a class method.

For the solution, we need only check the [docs for `enum`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v4.1.0/classes/ActiveRecord/Enum.html). Toward the bottom there's this example:

> In rare circumstances you might need to access the mapping directly. The mappings are exposed through a class method with the pluralized attribute name:
>
> ```
> Conversation.statuses # => { "active" => 0, "archived" => 1 }
> ```
>
> Use that class method when you need to know the ordinal value of an enum:
>
> ```
> Conversation.where("status <> ?", Conversation.statuses[:archived])
> ```
>
> Where conditions on an enum attribute must use the ordinal value of an enum.

Since Rails automatically creates scopes for enums, e.g. `User.doctor`, we can actually do better:

```
has_and_belongs_to_many :doctors, ->{ doctor }, class_name: "User"
```

You may be tempted to try to shorten this to the following:

```
has_and_belongs_to_many :doctors, &:doctor, class_name: "User"
```

...but as you've already discovered, that gives you a SyntaxError. The reason is that the `&` operator tells Ruby to convert the given object to a block and use it as the method's block argument. If the object isn't a proc (like `:doctor`), its `to_proc` method is called first, which is why e.g. `[1,2].reduce(&:+)` works. But the block must always be the last argument (and there can only be one), so you get a syntax error when you put another argument after `&:doctor`.

You could, however, do this:

```
has_and_belongs_to_many :doctors, :doctor.to_proc,
                        class_name: "User"
```

...but I don't think you really gain anything for it.

Comment: You're right about the difference between `doctor?` and `doctor` but could you please weigh in on why the ampersand syntax doesn't work in practice?

Comment: Sorry that wasn't clear. I've edited the last part of my answer to explain.